# Break a Foreach when counter reaches 5 | PHP

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, counter

I'm trying to stop the foreach when $counter reaches 5 , but i can't , i've tried to change the "break;" place , my try/catch inside the if,  but with no success, i keep getting 103 games(image) and I only want 5

```
.........
    $leagues= $api->getLeagueEntries("RANKED_SOLO_5x5", "Gold", 'I');
    
     $counter = 0;
    
     foreach ($leagues as $t=> $op) {
    
    if (++$counter < 5) {
    
      
    
    }
                try {
                    $account_id = $api->getSummoner($op->summonerId);
                    $date = time();
                    $ab = $api->getMatchlistByAccount($account_id->accountId,  "420", null, null, $date, NULL, null, null, null);
    
    
                    echo "<pre>" ; var_dump($ab);   echo "<pre>" ;
                      break;
                } catch (Exception $e) { }
            }
```

[image]

Comment: Is there some reason why `for ($i=0;$i<5;$i++) { /* do stuff with $leagues[i] */ }` wouldn't work?

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular $leagues is an array of objects so i need to access it properties

Comment: @LucasLn if `$leagues` is an array then what I suggest will work perfectly well. You'll just be looking for properties on the elements, as in `$account_id = $api->getSummoner($leagues[i]->summonerId);`

Comment: will try this  soon

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular I tested and your method works very well   , but do you know  a way to do with foreach , because i'm used to use foreach instead of for.

Comment: @Lucas Different structures exist for a reason. Your effort with `foreach` and a counter can be made to work, but why bother?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$leagues` is an array, so just loop through the array element by element and stop when you've done enough:

```
$limit = min(5, count($leagues));  // just in case there's fewer than five.
for ($i = 0; $i<limit; $i++) {
    $account_id = $api->getSummoner($leagues[$i]->summonerId);
    $date = time();
    $ab = $api->getMatchlistByAccount($account_id->accountId,  "420", null, null, $date, NULL, null, null, null);
    echo "<pre>" ; var_dump($ab);   echo "<pre>" ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to break away from a try. You could place the break in the else branch?

```
foreach (....) {
    if (++$counter < 5) {
        try  {..without break..}
        catch {}
    } else { break; }
}
```

Comment: keep getting the same result

Answer (score 0):

Try *array_slice* if you want to return only limited

```
echo "<pre>" ; var_dump(array_slice($ab, 0, 5));   echo "<pre>" ;
```

Comment: i get array_slice(): Argument #1 ($array) must be of type array , object given

Comment: if you see your loop is just running once as there is break statement right after echo "<pre>" ; var_dump($ab);   echo "<pre>" ; You need to check $api->getMatchlistByAccount as its returning you 103 records